# Spring batch: RollBack for CompositeItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring batch and currently working on reading multiple files using MultiResourceItemReader and write it into different tables of database using CompositeItemWriter, each file contains different number of lines.
My question: is it possible if one line failed to be inserted in database, to do ROLLBACK of all lines inserted of this file?
Is there a way to do a ROLLBACK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring batch reads and writes data in the form of chunks. Assume that you have 1000 records and your chunk size in 100 and you are doing batch inserts. For every chunk (100 items) spring batch would open a transaction, insert 100 records and commit the transaction. In case, if any error occurs that particular chunk (100 records) would be rolled back. But all the previous chunks that are already inserted cannot be rolled back.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. but if i don't have a fix number of items for a  transaction.for example first file has 100 items and the second has 104 items, the chunk size should be 104?  or is it possible that the chunk size depends on number of lines in file?

Comment: No. Chuck size can be anything. If you have 104, your ItemReader will read 100 items and will send 100 items to your ItemWriter. Your ItemWriter should do batch insert/update to the database. In the next chuck only 4 items will be read and inserted by your writer. In the next chunk ItemReader will return null since the end of file is reached. Hence the job would be terminated.